# Better ticks and tick labels with log scale

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to get better looking log-log plots and I almost got what I want except for a minor problem.

The reason my example throws off the standard settings is that the x values are confined within less than one decade and I want to use decimal, not scientific notation.

Allow me to illustrate with an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.6,0.83,1.1,1.8,2])
y = np.array([1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,0.1])

fig1,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

which produces:

[image: Fig1]

There are two problems with the x axis:

1. The use of scientific notation, which in this case is counterproductive
2. The horrible "offset" at the lower right corner

After much reading, I added three lines of code:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain',axis='x',useOffset=False)
```

This produces:

[image: Fig.2]

My understanding of this is that there are 5 minor ticks and 1 major one. It is much better, but still not perfect:

1. I would like some additional ticks between 1 and 2
2. Formatting of label at 1 is wrong. It should be "1.0"

So I inserted the following line before the formatter statement:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(0.2))
```

I finally get the ticks I want:

[image: Fig. 3]

I now have 8 major and 2 minor ticks. Now, this almost looks right except for the fact that the tick labels at 0.6, 0.8 and 2.0 appear bolder than the others. What is the reason for this and how can I correct it?

Comment: This might be a rendering artifact. For me it goes away if I save the figure with a higher resolution (`fig.savefig("test.png",dpi=300)`). It also goes away if I remove the `set_minor_formatter` line, but then you lose the minor ticks at 0.7 and 0.9.

Comment: 0.6 and 0.8 are bolder because they are being written as both minor tick labels and major tick labels; when it has rendered them, they must be slightly offset from each other, and thus they appear bolder.

Comment: @tom they are not offset, this is due to antialiasing of two perfectly overlapping texts.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Good point, I never realised that's the reason here. So when the texts are antialiased, are the partially filled pixels semi-transparent? Thus when you have two overlapping texts, those semi-transparent pixels become darker?

Comment: @tom Although antialiasing probably does not work with transparency as such, this would be the way one can best imagine what's going on. On the other hand, if you place two differently colored texts (or even lines) on top of each other you see some other effects, so it is not simply color mixing that is used for antialiasing. Probably this is getting a bit off-topic now.

Answer (score 6):

The reason, some of the labels appear bold is that they are part of the major and minor ticklabels. If two texts perfectly overlap, they appear bolder due to the antialiasing.
You may decide to only use minor ticklabels and set the major ones with a `NullLocator`.

Since the locations of the ticklabels you wish to have is really specific there is no automatic locator that would provide them out of the box. For this special case it may be easiest to use a `FixedLocator` and specify the labels you wish to have as a list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.6,0.83,1.1,1.8,2])
y = np.array([1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,0.1])

fig1,ax = plt.subplots(dpi=72, figsize=(6,4))
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

locs = np.append( np.arange(0.1,1,0.1),np.arange(1,10,0.2))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(locs))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator())

ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]

For a more generic labeling, one could of course subclass a locator, but we would then need to know the logic to use to determine the ticklabels. (As I do not see a well defined logic for the desired ticks from the question, I feel it would be wasted effort to provide such a solution for now.)

Comment: @IOBE, specifying the ticks explicitly is exactly what I **don't want** to do. However, your suggestion to use only one kind of ticks is a good one. I decided on using only major ticks and inserting this line now gives me very good looking ticks: `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.NullLocator())` (the set_minor_formatter line can also be removed).

Comment: Its not clear what you mean. How do you get the ticklabels `0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0` without setting them explicitely?

Comment: Let me clarify: The ticks I get are only major ticks multiple of 0.2. So there are no ticks at 0.7 or 0.9. matplotlib autoscales the axis for me, and I like that.

Comment: I don't see how that solves the question; but if you're happy with it, why not.