# Matplotlib Y Scale Modification

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using log as scale for Y-axis in my plot:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

However the problem is Y scale is displayed in such way that it goes from 10^0 to 10^1.
And there is no way one can know what are the in-between values.
Is there any way I can display the in between values in Y axis?

Comment: Sure, you can modify the ticks.

Comment: @BigBen I could not find any reference for that. Can you help me with that by mentioning the method name or something.

Comment: Lots of examples: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357576/better-ticks-and-tick-labels-with-log-scale), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale)....